# cellranger: how to convert a gtf file to string

Tags: python, bash, bioinformatics

I am using a **cellranger mkref** and faced with a strange python problem with GTF (custome gtf):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/lib/python/cellranger/reference.py", line 750, in validate_gtf
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/external/anaconda/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/external/anaconda/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gtf_to_gene_index', '/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/indexes', '/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/indexes/tmp74f_vsxg.json']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/bin/rna/mkref", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/bin/rna/mkref", line 130, in main
    reference_builder.build_gex_reference()
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/lib/python/cellranger/reference.py", line 613, in build_gex_reference
    self.validate_gtf()
  File "/home/user/cellranger-6.0.1/lib/python/cellranger/reference.py", line 753, in validate_gtf
    raise GexReferenceError("Error detected in GTF file: " + exc.output) from exc
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Also, I have the similar gtf file, which cellranger accepts without problems. I compared those files (moreover, the firs one i made from the second one):

file 1: `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`
file 2: `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Also, I checked with `cat -vE` and the files is the same

How can I change the file?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue. The problem was in duplicated IDs in my GTF file. Removing those duplicates solved the issue. See the discussion on Cellranger GitHub: https://github.com/10XGenomics/cellranger/issues/125

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "duplicated IDs" - duplicated gene_id on different chromosomes or something another problem?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. It means that there are two or more genes with the same "gene_id". Does not matter on which chromosome they are. ID must be unique.

Comment: eventually I found and removed duplicated gene_id on different chromosomes and your answer was right! Thank you for your help!